# Can't get gh-pages to work with Angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, github, github-pages

I am working on an Angular project and wanted to host the project through GitHub with gh-pages.

Since the index.html file was not in the root directory, I created an empty branch off of my master and called it gh-pages. I then copied my files into the new branch, so that the index.html file was in the root directory.

I am also using Grunt, so I copied the grunt generated app.js file into the root directory as well. I can now see the project in the browser if I go to http://kelseysteele.github.io/votm3/#/home, however the navigation bar is missing and the other pages, like http://kelseysteele.github.io/votm3/#/overview,  are not working properly.

I've been stuck on this for a few days and would really appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: Check your relative urls, since your project files are contained within the `votm` folder on github.

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, you'll see errors: `GET http://kelseysteele.github.io/data/overview-data.json 404 (Not Found)`

Fix the url here: https://github.com/KelseySteele/votm3/blob/master/src/votm3/Scripts/controllers/overview-controller.js#L10

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using grunt, you will want to build the project before serving the files. This will make the files and code modules build properly before serving the index.html. A popular module you can use is https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-gh-pages an get your builds serving properly.

Comment: Thanks for the link to this module. It seems like this is the way to go, but I've been having trouble installing the plugin. When I run "ls" in the node command prompt, I see "grunt-gh-pages@1.0.0' within the main directory of my computer, but it doesn't seem to be within the project's directory. When I run grunt in Visual Studio, I get the following error: "Local Npm module 'grunt-gh-pages' not found. Is it installed?" Any idea for how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you install grunt-gh-pages with `npm install grunt-gh-pages --save-dev` and executed `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-gh-pages');` in your `gruntfile.js`? If so, you should see grunt-gh-pages appear as part of your dev dependencies in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks again! That did get rid of the "Local Npm module 'grunt-gh-pages'" error. However, now I seem to be stuck again. I added the grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-gh-pages') and grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['gh-pages']); to the gruntfile.js file  and changed the base option within grunt.initConfig to be 'src'. Now I get an error that says: "Fatal error: The 'base' option must be an existing directory". It seems that the src file is the directory where my index.html file is located, so shouldn't that be the base? I've looked at a lot of different sources, but nothing has helped.